# null pointer en GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo un ejercicio tonto con un `grindview` donde debe de sacarme por 3 columnas el abecedarios pero da un `nullpointer` en el set adapte, pero el código es copiado del profesor y la idea es entenderlo, pero no se porque falla

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gridView;
    private TextView tv1;
    static final String[] letras = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
            "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S","T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gv1);
        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, letras);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String resultado = (String) ((TextView) v).getText();
                tv1.setText(resultado);
            }
        });
    }
}


?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gw1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y el logcat

> 2020-01-03 20:21:43.751 14860-14860/com.example.ej8 E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.ej8, PID: 14860
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ej8/com.example.ej8.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>               at com.example.ej8.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2673)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que tienes un error en la referencia a tu GridView, el id es gw2 y en el código pusiste gv1.

Luego el código funciona bien, si lo quieres en 3 columnas tienes que agregar la propiedad android:numColumns="3" Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"/>
```

En ver de 3, puedes indicar "auto_fit".

Puedes encontrar atributos muy interesantes para el GridView,

```
android:columnWidth //Ancho fijo para la columna
android:gravity // Gravedad dentro de la celda
android:horizontalSpacing // Espaciado horizontal entre columnas
android:numColumns   // Número de columnas
android:stretchMode  // Defines cómo se estiran las columnas para rellenar espacios vacios
android:verticalSpacing // Espaciado vertical entre filas.
```

Un saludo.

P.D. En la documentación puedes encontrar muchas cosas interesantes para aplicar al [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView).

Comment: lo mirare gracias, el ejercicio es copiado y pegado el codigo dle profesor por eso la sorpresa de que de error